# RaspberryPi - psutil 2.1.1 install error

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, raspberry-pi, psutil

I installed psutil on my RPi from `sudo apt-get install python-psutil` but it gave me v0.5.1

I want to use v2.1.1 since it has the virtual_memory() command where v0.5.1 does not.

While attempting to upgrade psutil from PIP, `sudo pip install --upgrade psutil` it starts installing then quits with this error:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade psutil                                                                                                                                                             
Downloading/unpacking psutil from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/psutil/psutil-2.1.1.tar.gz#md5=72a6b15d589fab11f6ca245b775bc3c6                                                                 
  Downloading psutil-2.1.1.tar.gz (216kB): 216kB downloaded                                                                                                                                                 
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/psutil/setup.py) egg_info for package psutil                                                                                                                   

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'                                                                                                                  
Installing collected packages: psutil                                                                                                                                                                       
  Found existing installation: psutil 0.5.1                                                                                                                                                                 
    Can't uninstall 'psutil'. No files were found to uninstall.                                                                                                                                             
  Running setup.py install for psutil                                                                                                                                                                       
    building '_psutil_linux' extension                                                                                                                                                                      
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c psutil/_psutil_linux.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o      
    In file included from /usr/include/linux/kernel.h:4:0,                                                                                                                                                  
                     from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/sysinfo.h:25,                                                                                                                                
                     from psutil/_psutil_linux.c:21:                                                                                                                                                        
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:8:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_long_t'                                                                                                                            
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:9:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                           
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:10:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:11:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:12:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:13:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:14:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:15:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:18:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:19:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'                                                                                                                          
    /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:21:22: error: '__kernel_ulong_t' undeclared here (not in a function)                                                                                                       
    psutil/_psutil_linux.c: In function 'init_psutil_linux':                                                                                                                                                
    psutil/_psutil_linux.c:475:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]                                                                                                            
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried uninstalling python-psutil using `sudo apt-get remove --purge python-psutil` then doing `sudo pip install psutil` but comes back with the same error. Same story with `sudo easy_install psutil`

Next I tried to make sure I had `python-dev` and `libevent-dev` installed. `python-dev` was already installed and updated but `libevent-dev` was not. so I updated it and tried `sudo pip install psutil` again to no avail (same error).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Also tried downloading and manually installing 2.1.1 using `sudo python setup.py install` from the un-tar'd psutil directory with the same error.

Comment: A [solution I found](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=523999&sid=eb810a0d5173e168999786d6c3461e91#p523999) involves editing my sysinfo.h file, not sure if I want to do that or not.